# Using QScopedPointer in conjunction with Qt's parent-child hierarchy

Tags: c++, qt

Consider following code. Does it delete QWidget twice when object of Test class gets deleted? I guess deletion would be twice, once by Test class as it is set as parent of QWidget object and once by QScopedPointer?

Is correct solution is to pass nullptr as parent of QWidget in constructor?

```
class Test : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {
        widgetPtr.reset(new QWidget(this)); // Passing Test to QWidget constructor
    }

private:
    QScopedPointer<QWidget> widgetPtr;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example can be simplified:

```
TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    {
        QObject* parent{new QObject};
        QObject* child{new QObject{parent}};
        delete child;
        delete parent;
    }
    {
        QObject* parent{new QObject};
        QObject* child{new QObject{parent}};
        delete parent;
    }
}
```

Both above approaches are correct, there is no memory leak and there is no double `delete`.

In the first case, when child object is deleted, `QObject` destructor removes it from its parent children list. I couldn't find it mentioned explicitly in the documentation, but it is clear from the [QT source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp?h=v5.6.0#n1040). Then when you `delete parent` it doesn't `delete` the child again.

In the second case `QObject parent` destructor deletes the `child`, because it is still on its children list.

Back to your original code, you can use `QScopedPointer` like in your example, you can also use `std::unique_ptr`, or a raw pointer (only if you provide a parent). If you decide to use a smart pointer, then passing a parent is not necessary for the sake of memory management, so you can provide it or not, depends if you consider your `widget` to be a child of your `Test` (I think yes), and if you would like to profit from [findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#findChild).

Comment: I've one more query, when object of Test class gets destroyed, whom it kills first, QWidget object which I'm creating in constructor or QScopedPointer? I think if QWidget object is being deleted first, then on deletion of QScopedPointer, would not that call delete again on QWidget object? Sorry, if that question is dumb but I was skeptical due to double delete scenario. I hope you got my query :)

Comment: @Infinity it's opposite; `~Test` destructor first destroys all member fields in the order opposite to their declaration in the class body, then `~QObject` superclass destructor is called. So first your `QScopedPointer<QWidget> widgetPtr;` is destroyed, and then `QObject` is destroying all its children, but at that point object previously pointed by `widgetPtr` is not its child anymore.